Published on webserver core8 api works from POSTMAN and from weserver published frontend but ERR_CONNECTION_RESET from client browser
I was trying to explain everything on the subject, but here's my problem:
I have a webApi developed with netcore 8, published on a windows server 2012 with IIS 8, and an Angular 15 frontend, hosted on the same webserver.
If I try to access the webapi with PostMan, all works correctly and the response is sent back with everything i need.
If i try to access the webapi using the Angular client directly with a browser on the webserver, it works correctly (the request is from a login form).
If i try to access the webapi using the Angular client from a client browser i have an error in the console "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".
I tried with different browser from different clients: same error.
The original web.config of the API is the following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath=".\WebApi.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    
    </location>
</configuration>

Any guess?
P.S.: The webApi was originally written for netcore7 and worked on the same environment without any problem
I have tried a more complex version of web.config as follow:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <remove name="WebDAV" />
                <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
                <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
                <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
                <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
                <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
                <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
                <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
            </modules>
            <aspNetCore processPath=".\WebApi.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Authorization"/>
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
        </system.webServer>
    
    </location>
</configuration>

But still doesn't work.
More information:
in the webapi startup i added the UseUrls("https://*:4000")
in the appsettings of the webapi i have specified a "AppURL" : "https://webserverName/:4000" that is the same used in the app.config of the angular client: "apiEndpoint":"https://webserverName:4000/".
The Angular client run on http, while the webApi run on https (with self signed SSL cert).

I would say it is a CORS problem

make sure both frontend and backend use same protocol:  should both be https.  Your api endpoints can't have the same URL... usually those would be same-domain but in different route/path at the end.  Ex:  angular served from https://www.webservername.com (index.html, that's angular served from special wwwroot dir), and endpoints configured at https://www.webservername.com/api/ (.NET controllers).  Not sure why you specify a port there.  "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" sounds like a refused connection, but you'd need to debug further on the backend to get more details there... might be at IIS level.

If you’re receiving the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error message, it means that your internet browser is unable to connect to the target website’s server. You need to make sure that the necessary ports (443 for HTTPS) are open in your Windows Firewall or any other firewall software you have installed. If a firewall blocks incoming HTTPS traffic, it may cause a connection reset error.

@samwu i hardly think could it be a firewall problem, the address used by the angular client is the same used in POSTMAN, where the call works correctly.

@browsermator if there was a problem with protocol it shouldn't work also from the webserver itself, where instead everything works correctly.

@Andrei as for the CORS, my service in the configuration has a useUrl with *, shouldn't this mean it accept connection coming from every address? Shouldn't this eventually prevent even the connection from POSTMAN?

Postman has no CORS rules.  Only the browsers do that.  You should know that wildcards are not allowed for requests with credentials and/or secure.  Still, you'd receive a CORS error there, so you need to check the full exception server side for that ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

You can try to find information about server errors by looking in the log files or Event Vierer, the error message may help you identify the problem.

Log files from ISS only have the successful call from the client when using it in a browser from the webserver itself, but it has no errors for the client from remote browser.
I also made some test adding on the "withOrigin": localhost, webservername and the webserver IP: no luck

It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

In the end I resolved my own problem that was, indeed, a CORS problem.
My frontend was running using http while my service was running on https.
Switching to http my service (not wanting to deal with certificates) did the trick.
I guess I need to go more deeply into CORS
